# How to represent / in regex in awk

Tags: shell, awk

I am looking for a regex in awk

```
request/123(Pattern for searching) request(word for matching)
word=request pattern =request/123
```

**REGEX USED**

```
if(word ~ /Pattern"/"*/)
```

I am facing an error as I am not able to use / inside the regex.Could someone help me regarding this. Thank you

Comment: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=awk+search+slashes -- the first result has the answer.

Comment: I used double quotes I am still not able to fix this\

Comment: I fixed it and I want to know only one .. Can we use variables inside a regex .. I searched for this but was not able to get the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the first result at http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=awk+search+slashes, indicate a slash is a literal slash by preceding it with a backslash [the *escape character*].

```
if(word ~ /Pattern\/*/)
```

Comment: Can we use variables inside regex if so how ?